# How to use web browser as VNC client?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop

I want to remotely login my user in the web browser, but I don't know how to do this.

I am using "Redhat" and I am properly setup vnc server without any I am using vnc client for remotely access.

but now a want to remotely login into the "Web Browser" like below image how can I do that.

I have tried:

"TightVNC", but when I try to remotely login with the help of "tightVNC" it is open a "Java applet" but i want the output like below image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose my VNC Server  : 192.168.100.195

Install git:

```
yum install git
```

after that download noVNC

```
$git clone git://github.com/kanaka/noVNC   

$ cd noVNC
$ ./utils/launch.sh --vnc 192.168.100.195:5901
```

after that you get output like:

```
Warning: could not find self.pem
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 6080
WebSocket server settings:
  - Listen on :6080
  - Flash security policy server
  - Web server. Web root: /home/xmodulo/noVNC
  - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
  - proxying from :6080 to 192.168.1.10:5900

Navigate to this URL:

    http://127.0.0.1:6080/vnc.html?host=127.0.0.1&port=6080

Press Ctrl-C to exit
```

after that:
    http://127.0.0.1:6080/vnc.html?host=127.0.0.1&port=6080

and finally i m get the out like below image

and it is use in openstack :)

[image]

Comment: is there any way to run it without creating new web server ? Suppose I have web page and on click i want to open this page ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the realvnc chrome plugin?

https://www.realvnc.com/products/chrome/

Comment: i m dont want to use any plugin.

Comment: Have you seen NoVNC? http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/noVNC/vnc.html:  


"noVNC is a browser based VNC client implemented using HTML5 Canvas and WebSockets. You will either need a VNC server with WebSockets support (such as libvncserver) or you will need to use websockify to bridge between your browser and VNC server. See the noVNC README and website for more information. 
Close"